# Moving GObject in Java

Tags: java

Good morning guys, I am new to Java, therefore I hope you will be able to help me. So, here is the problem I faced. BTW, I am ought to use ASM Graphics.

That is my Gobject class

```
package objects;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.*;

public class Mario extends GCompound implements ActionListener{
public static double dx;
public static double dy;
public static GImage mario;
private static int x = 40;
private static int y = 350;
private final int min = 350;
private final int gravity = 5;
private final int speed = 5;
private final int max_jump = min - 220;
private int direction;
private int number = 1;
public static boolean standing = true;

public Mario () {
    if (standing == true) {
        mario = new GImage("Mario_Big_Right_Still.png");
        mario.setSize(60, 105);
    }
    else {
        mario = new GImage("Mario_Big_Crouch_Left.png");
        mario.setSize(60, 95);
    }
    mario.setLocation(x + dx, y + dy);
    add(mario);
}

public boolean onBottom() {
        if (mario.getLocation().getY() >= min ) return true;
    return false;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            standing = false;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 5;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            standing = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And here is the application file

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import objects.Mario;

public class Application extends GraphicsProgram implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WINDOW_WiDTH = 800;
public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
public static final int REFRESH = 60;
public int dx;
public int dy;

public void run () {
    setSize(WINDOW_WiDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    addKeyListeners();
    while (true) {
        Mario mario = new Mario();
        add(mario);
        mario.setLocation(mario.getLocation().getX() + dx, mario.getLocation().getY() + dy);
        pause(REFRESH);
    }
}
}
```

Moreover, I need to be able to change the images as well. Any recommendations are very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're asking of us with this question...I see code and I see a few sentences related to what you're doing, but I'm not sure of what it is specifically that you're asking.

Comment: And where is that problem you face?

Comment: @Makoto I am asking to help me with creating an animation of movement. The problem I face is that when I click on arrows, nothing happens, the program does not see me pressing the keys.

Comment: @f1sh The problem is that I am not able to gey my keylisteners working. addKeylisteners(); does not work as well